# I keep getting a Non-exhaustive patterns error

Tags: haskell

I've tested my code on Jupyter where it works fine, but for some reason in Haskell I get some sort of error

```
getCount :: String -> Int
getCount (x:xs) = sum[ 1 |c<- (x:xs), check c]
                      where check :: Char -> Bool
                            check v = any(v==)['a','o','e','i','u']
```

Error

```
uncaught exception: PatternMatchFail
src/Codewars/Kata/Vowel.hs:(4,1)-(6,67): Non-exhaustive patterns in function getCount

(after 1 test)
  0
```

[image]

Comment: Try running `getCount ""` in Jupyter. That should give you the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(x:xs)` pattern does not match the empty string (list). You do not need to pattern match, you can work with:

```
getCount :: String -> Int
getCount xs = sum [ 1 | c<- xs, check c]
                      where check :: Char -> Bool
                            check v = `any (v ==) ['a','o','e','i','u']
```

You can simplify this to:

```
getCount :: String -> Int
getCount xs = sum [ 1 | c<- xs, c `elem` "aeiou"]
```

or even work with `filter`:

```
getCount :: String -> Int
getCount = length . filter (`elem` "aeiou")
```